# Requires newer sdk version #21 (current version is #15)

Tags: android, android-studio

Err... I'm trying to run the "FloatingActionButtonBasic" example on my android device, and getting this error... Is it possible to downgrade my android studio to that old api? What should I do?

And I want to mention, ActionBarCompat-Basic is running without problems, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

you should also include the build.gradle file. may be you have something like this-

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
```

in this case, check **FloatingActionButtonBasic** min required api level first in documentation. if that allows to use this library in api level **15** , then change those lines in build.gradle file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems like I can. Just download stuff for older api from sdk manager. It also have separate samples, current ones not always work for 15.